# Efficient way to save DOM elements in an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, object, dom

Is there a efficient way to save DOM elements in an object variable like this:

http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/357570example.png?

The aim is to preserve some elements of the DOM object in a variable to be able to add attributes.

I can actually go through data- attributes in HTML5 but I prefer a pure JavaScript (JQuery too) solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply store a collection of `DOM` Elements in a variable.

For example,

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
```

The variable `inputs` will contain a live collection of input elements you can refer to later for manipulating.

For example, you can iterate over this collection and add a CSS class using a simple for loop like:

```
for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){
  inputs[i].classList.add("newClass");
}
```

For setting an attribute, you can use the `setAttribute()` method.

---

You can do the very same in jquery as well, only the syntax for accessing the elements will change.

For example,

```
var inputs = $("input");
```

You can iterate over the jQuery object inputs using it's `each()` method like

```
inputs.each(function(){
  $(this).addClass("newClass");
});
```

For setting an attribute to an element using jQuery, you can use it's `attr()` method.

Comment: Yes I know this way.

But if I want to save each input separately in an object (in object )(for add some attributes), how do I do ?

Comment: Can you elaborate, what you mean by *save each input in an object*? an element itself is an object,. And you can use `setAttribute()` method to add attributes to it.

Comment: Juste like here : http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/357570example.png

Imagine p and h1 just like an input. "data1" and "data2" refer to their parent object. I would like to add some data on each DOM elements with JS.

Is this possible ? To save elements and dynamically add some data.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me you are looking for something like this:

```
var foo = {
    p: document.getElementById('some-id'),
    h1: document.getElementById('some-other-id')
};

foo.p.data1 = "something";
foo.p.data2 = "something else";

// etc...
```

The code above saves the elements that have id `some-id` and `some-other-id` in the fields `p` and `h1` of the object `foo`. It also sets the fields `data1` and `data2` on `foo.p`. The same could be done on `foo.h1`.

Note that if some other code seeks the element that has id `some-id` that code will see `data1` and `data2` on the element. That is, the fields your code adds is visible to everyone.

Modern browsers accept adding arbitrary fields on DOM elements. Older browsers won't necessarily accept it. I don't have a list of browser that will allow it and those that won't. I would advise using something more expressive than `data1`. In particular such field should be specific enough to avoid a name clash. When I do this, I prefix my field names with the name of my application.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your response. This is what I want to do but dynamically ie by making a scan of the dom looking for elements and placing them in javascript objects. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found how I could make this, by passing by an object constructor like this :

```
function objectConstructor( element ) {
    this.element = element;
    this.data1 = "string";
    this.data2 =  "string";
}
```

In any way, thank you for your response.